# How to display a string at the right of the user insert prompt

Tags: bash, terminal, echo, read, printf

I have simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
SENTENCE=""
while read word
do
    SENTENCE="$SENTENCE $word"
done
```

whose interaction with the user may result in the following:

```
a
a
b
a b
c
a b c
d
a b c d
```

How can I have the string displayed at the right in the same line as the user in order to have the output

```
a                                 a
b                                 a b
c                                 a b c
d                                 a b c d
```

Comment: How can I complete this AINSI sequence: `echo -e "\e[1a b c d"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the simplest case (a short word, no line-wrapping, no concern about reaching the end of the screen with scrolling), you could do this

```
#!/bin/bash
SENTENCE=""
tput sc
while read word
do
    SENTENCE="$SENTENCE $word"
    tput rc
    tput hpa 20
    printf '%s\n' "$SENTENCE"
    tput sc
done
```

That uses two terminal features which are in most of the terminal descriptions you would use:

- save/restore cursor position (the **`sc`** and **`rc`** parameters), and
- horizontal position (the **`hpa`** parameter).

You could hardcode the corresponding escape sequences, at the expense of readability...

By the way, some may suggest using the up-arrow escape, but that has the same problem with scrolling at the end of the screen, as also would `\e[F` (`CPL`, which is not in your terminal description).

For moving horizontally, you could use the right-cursor with a parameter, e.g.,

```
tput cuf 20
```

which would be `\e[20C`.

At the end of the question, there is comment about **`\e[1a`**, but ANSI escape sequences are case-dependent, that is not the same as **`\e[1A`** (which moves the cursor up by one line).  This may be what you had in mind:

```
#!/bin/bash
SENTENCE=""
while read word
do
    SENTENCE="$SENTENCE $word"
    tput cuu1
    tput hpa 20
    printf '%s\n' "$SENTENCE"
done
```

which is easier to read than

```
#!/bin/bash
SENTENCE=""
while read word
do
    SENTENCE="$SENTENCE $word"
    echo -en '\e[A'
    echo -en '\e[20C'
    echo "$SENTENCE"
done
```

Comment: Thank for your extended answer. It is now part of the interactive mode of screen-generator (https://github.com/boddhissattva/screen-generator)